# How to resolve the hybrid search crawl error in sp2013?

Tags: azure, sharepoint-2013, hybrid

I am trying to setup a Hybrid search on the Azure server, where I have installed SharePoint 2013, August 2020 CU. The Azure AD sync is configured and synchronization works fine.
The STS certificates are added to the server's "Trusted root certificate authority).
The Hybrid search is created and configured with the scripts (CreateCloudSSA.ps1 and Onboard-CloudHybridSearch.ps1) from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51490.

The Cloud search service application throws crawl errors and none of the contents get crawled successfully.
[image: Crawl errors]
and I am finding below logs in ULS:

```
mssearch.exe (0x153C)   0x3EF4  SharePoint Server Search    Crawler:Gatherer Plugin dra4    High    CGthrPrj::AdviseStatusChange : advising status change NSC_FLUSH (Portal_Content 4dfd52bb-b019-44e8-a044-34296ca908ed-crawl-0 )  [cgatherprj.cxx:1648]  search\native\gather\gthrsvc\cgatherprj.cxx  
mssearch.exe (0x153C)   0x3EF4  SharePoint Server Search    Crawler:Gatherer Plugin ds7h    High    CPluginCollection::AdviseStatusChange : advising status change NSC_FLUSH (Portal_Content 4dfd52bb-b019-44e8-a044-34296ca908ed-crawl-0 )  [plugin.cxx:712]  search\native\gather\gthrsvc\plugin.cxx  
mssearch.exe (0x153C)   0x3EF4  SharePoint Server Search    Crawler:Gatherer Plugin ds7h    High    CPluginCollection::AdviseStatusChange : advising status change NSC_FLUSH (Portal_Content 4dfd52bb-b019-44e8-a044-34296ca908ed-crawl-0 )  [plugin.cxx:712]  search\native\gather\gthrsvc\plugin.cxx  
mssearch.exe (0x153C)   0x1550  SharePoint Server Search    Crawler:Azure Plugin    amn0h   High    AzureServiceProxy::GetAzureTenantInfo caught AggregateException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send., unable to get EndpointAddress, submit is blocked    
mssearch.exe (0x153C)   0x1550  SharePoint Server Search    Crawler:Azure Plugin    amn0i   High    AzureServiceProxy caught Exception: *** Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.AzureSearchService.AzureException: AzurePlugin was not able to get Tenant Info from configuration server     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.AzureSearchService.AzureServiceProxy.GetAzureTenantInfo(String portalURL, String realm, String& returnPropertyValue, String propertyName)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.AzureSearchService.AzureServiceProxy.SubmitDocuments(String azureServiceLocation, String authRealm, String SPOServiceTenantID, String SearchContentService_ContentFarmId, String portalURL, String testId, String encryptionCert, Boolean allowUnencryptedSubmit, sSubmitDocument[] documents, sDocumentResult[]& results, sAzureRequestInfo& RequestInfo) ***    
mssearch.exe (0x153C)   0x1550  SharePoint Server Search    Crawler:Azure Plugin    amn30   High    CAzurePlugin::SubmitTaskInternal Failed to SubmitDocuments with hr : 0x80040dd0  [azurepiobj.cxx:941]  search\native\gather\plugins\azurepi\azurepiobj.cxx  
mssearch.exe (0x153C)   0x1550  SharePoint Server Search    Crawler:Common  15y3    High    >>>> Exception hr=0x80040dd0 eip=00007FF8DA005DBD module=search\native\gather\plugins\azurepi\azurepiobj.cxx line=942   
mssearch.exe (0x153C)   0x1550  SharePoint Server Search    Crawler:Azure Plugin    amn3o   High    CAzurePlugin::SubmitTask caught NLBaseException AzureException AzurePlugin was not able to get Tenant Info from configuration server hr=80040DD0  [azurepiobj.cxx:701]  search\native\gather\plugins\azurepi\azurepiobj.cxx 
mssearch.exe (0x153C)   0x1550  SharePoint Server Search    Crawler:Gatherer Service    fus3    Medium  Transaction failed in plugin RUZA Url sts4s://sharepoint.XXXXXXXX.com/siteurl=/siteid={85fb69d8-18fe-4c5e-a70b-5b2800ad996f}/weburl=/webid={89ad9853-e1cd-43f3-a9a2-55d50515b23f}/listid={2dfde8eb-8446-4cd2-b974-eee4c9705a28}/folderurl=/itemid=14 Error 0x80040dd0  [gthrtrx.cxx:953]  search\native\gather\gthrsvc\gthrtrx.cxx  2d2d7a23-5fd5-4eb4-b6a8-d5cda36df878
```

Could I get help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the ULS log for time out error message. Increase the time out. Found this that helped in resolving the issue where content from online were not getting displayed. https://ekhichdi.com/2021/07/05/sharepoint-hybrid-search-not-giving-result-from-sharepoint-online/